# How to add to a dictionary through a text file

Tags: python, file, text, dictionary

I want to add to a dictionary through a text file. Basically my text file is this:

```
year3test 0
year4test 0
year5test 0
year6test 0
```

I want to add these to a blank dictionary titled `totals = {}` with year3test, year4test being the keys with the 0s being the totals, so that my dictionary looks like this:

```
totals = {
"year3test" : 0
"year4test" : 0
"year5test" : 0
"year6test" : 0
}
```

How should I go about this? Apologies, I am very new to python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: python docs is a goog place to start then... http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict(line.split() for line in open('path/to/input'))
```

Or, the more verbose way:

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    answer = {}
    for line in infile:
        k,v = line.split()
        answer[k] = v
```

Comment: on the verbose way, when i use it i get an error saying "k, v = line.split
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 0):

eval?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

a = {'hello':1,'what':2,'which':3} #a is dict

with open ("file1.txt","w") as f:
    f.write ('%s' % a) # creating file.  you may type it to see how it made (text)

b = ''
with open ("file1.txt","r") as f:
    b = eval(f.read()) # reading dict file and converting it to dict.

print type(b) # b is dict.
```